# FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1 scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can't launch application in debug mode on simulator,
Error:-  FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will happen if you try to set empty environment variable in Edit scheme, uncheck that environment variable.[Refer this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d6R5.png)